# Javafx: listening to widthProperty change in Controller.java

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code in Controller.java:

```
package sample;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller{
@FXML
HBox fontBox;

Stage stage = (Stage) fontBox.getScene().getWindow();
Scene scene = stage.getScene();

scene.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    stage.setTitle(newVal.toString()); //test
    int newSize = Integer.parseInt(newVal.toString());

});

}
```

IntelliJ doesn't recognize widthProperty and says addListener is invalid method declaration. Does anyone know how to fix that.

Comment: Can you add the imports you are using to the code in the question? Include the entire controller if it is not too much code.

Comment: I added the whole controller.java

Comment: You made some mistake in copying and pasting. That code is not in a method.

Comment: Thank you. I still can get it to  recognize  widthProperty. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block of code below needs to go in the constructor or initialize method of your controller to be recognized by Intellij:

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    stage.setTitle(newVal.toString()); //test
    int newSize = Integer.parseInt(newVal.toString());

});
```

Intellij does not recognize it because statements need to appear inside of a block of code.